# The requested package robmorgan/phinx No version set (parsed as 1.0.0) is satisfiable by robmorgan/phinx[No version set (parsed as 1.0.0)]

Tags: php, cakephp, composer-php, command-line-interface, phinx

When trying to install phinx executed the below command and it's giving the error as below

```
php composer.phar require robmorgan/phinx

Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
  Problem 1
    - The requested package robmorgan/phinx No version set (parsed as 1.0.0) is satisfiable by robmorgan/phinx[No version set (parsed as 1.0.0)] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
```

Comment: there is no robmorgan/phinx tagged version >= 1.0.0. So you have to add the version constraint, too, ie.: `php composer.phar require robmorgan/phinx:^0.9.1` If that does not work please provide your composer.json

Comment: Thanks for the response. actual mistake I've made was suggested slash in phinx was not worked in windows.

Comment: It's resolved by using forward slash